# Should I bother moving stuff from vimrc to gvimrc?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, macvim, gvimrc

Is is worth moving gui-related options out of my vimrc and into a gvimrc if there's only a couple such options? I'm kind of inclined to keep everything in one place and house gui options inside `if` statements, but is there a compelling argument to do otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you don't depend on the execution order (`.vimrc` is sourced first, `.gvimrc` last, after all plugins; most options have no such dependency), it's an arbitrary decision where to place the GUI-only settings.

You can just put those into `~/.vimrc`, surrounded by

```
:if has('gui_running')
    ..
:endif
```

#### Caveat

Apparently, if you start terminal Vim and only later switch to GUI mode (via `:gui`; this works f.e. on Linux Vim), the `.gvimrc` file is belatedly sourced, so that's one special case where your consolidated approach wouldn't work.